# Rewriting search button from web forms application to mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web forms application with a service reference
and I need to rewrite only the front-end of it in mvc4

I'm having trouble with search button (still new to programming)
this is the code of it in web forms

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ClearViewers();
        btnSearch.Enabled = false;
        btnSyncronise.Enabled = false;

        PersonalInformation localInfo = null;
        PersonInfo[] registryInfo = null;

        needsUpdate = false;

        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;


        try
        {
            if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPersonalNumber.Text)) || (txtPersonalNumber.Text.Length != 11) || (Regex.Match(txtPersonalNumber.Text, "^\\d{11}$").Success == false))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"blabla" + Environment.NewLine + @"blablabla" + Environment.NewLine + @"blabla", @"blabla", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            using (PersonalInfoServiceClient proxy = new PersonalInfoServiceClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    localInfo = proxy.GetLocalInfoForPerson(txtPersonalNumber.Text.Trim());

                    if (localInfo != null)
                    {

                        ssStatusLocal.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        ssStatusLocal.Text = @"found personal ID";

                        lblFirstName.Text = localInfo.FirstName;
                        lblLastName.Text = localInfo.LastName;
                        lblMiddleName.Text = localInfo.MiddleName;
                        lblBirthDate.Text = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", localInfo.BirthDate);

                        if (localInfo.PersonStatus == PersonStatus.Active)
                            lblStatus.Text = @"active";

                        else if (localInfo.PersonStatus == PersonStatus.Rejected)
                            lblStatus.Text = @"passive";

                        else if (localInfo.PersonStatus == PersonStatus.Dead)
                            lblStatus.Text = @"dead";

                        else
                            lblStatus.Text = @"unknown";


                        lblSex.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(localInfo.Sex) == 1) ? @"male" : @"female";
                        lblAddress.Text = localInfo.Address;
                        lbBirthPlace.Text = localInfo.BirthPlace;
                        lbCitizenShip.Text = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(localInfo.CitizenShip) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(localInfo.CitizenShipCode)) ? localInfo.CitizenShip : localInfo.CitizenShip + " / " + localInfo.CitizenShipCode;
                        lbDoubleCitizenShip.Text = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(localInfo.DoubleCitizenShip) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(localInfo.DoubleCitizenShipCode)) ? localInfo.DoubleCitizenShip : localInfo.DoubleCitizenShip + " / " + localInfo.DoubleCitizenShipCode;
                        lblRegion.Text = localInfo.RegionName;

                        if (localInfo.Photo != null)
                        {
                            MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(localInfo.Photo);
                            pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(MS);
                        }

                        documentInformationBindingSource1.DataSource = localInfo.Documents;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ssStatusLocal.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        ssStatusLocal.Text = @"personal ID not found";
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    ssStatusLocal.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    ssStatusLocal.Text = @"error";

                    throw;
                }


                try
                {
                    registryInfo = proxy.GetRegistryInfoForPerson(txtPersonalNumber.Text.Trim());

                    if (registryInfo != null && registryInfo.Length > 0)
                    {

                        ssStatusCivil.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        ssStatusCivil.Text = @"found personal ID";

                        btnSyncronise.Enabled = true;

                        RegistryPersonInfos list = new RegistryPersonInfos();
                        foreach (PersonInfo personInfo in registryInfo)
                        {
                            RegistryPersonInfo registryPersonInfo = new RegistryPersonInfo()
                            {
                                BirthDate = personInfo.BirthDate
                                ,
                                IsDead = (personInfo.IsPersonDead) ? "yes" : "no"
                                ,
                                FirstName = personInfo.FirstName
                                ,
                                LastName = personInfo.LastName
                                ,
                                MiddleName = personInfo.MiddleName
                                ,
                                DocumentStatusName = personInfo.DocumentStatusStr
                                ,
                                DocumentStatus = personInfo.DocumentStatusEnum.ToString()
                                ,
                                PersonalNumber = personInfo.PrivateNumber
                                ,
                                DocumentRejectDate = personInfo.RejectedDate
                                ,
                                DocumentType = (personInfo.IsIdCard) ? (string.IsNullOrEmpty(personInfo.IdCardNumber)) ? "one" : "two" : "three"
                                ,
                                DocumentSerie = (personInfo.IsIdCard) ? personInfo.IdCardSerial : string.Empty
                                ,
                                DocumentNumber = (personInfo.IsIdCard) ? (string.IsNullOrEmpty(personInfo.IdCardNumber)) ? string.Empty : personInfo.IdCardNumber : personInfo.PaspNumber
                            };

                            list.Add(registryPersonInfo);
                        }

                        registryPersonInfoBindingSource.DataSource = list;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ssStatusCivil.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        ssStatusCivil.Text = @"Personal ID not found";
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    ssStatusCivil.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    ssStatusCivil.Text = @"error";
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            lblFirstName.Text = String.Empty;
            lblLastName.Text = String.Empty;
            lblMiddleName.Text = String.Empty;
            lblStatus.Text = String.Empty;
            needsUpdate = false;
            dgwMain.DataSource = null;

            MessageBox.Show(
                String.Format(
                    "error during loading. {0} error: {1} {2} info: {3}",
                    Environment.NewLine, x.Message, Environment.NewLine,
                    (x.InnerException == null) ? string.Empty : x.InnerException.Message), @"Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            btnSearch.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

how do you write this in controller?
the controller can't find labels, there is no picturebox
I have no idea how to get data via service reference

could you help ?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

Comment: Web Forms and MVC are very different.  They are constructed differently.  Look at the music store tutorial that will go over all of the basics of mvc.  The controller can't "see" any of the view elements like web forms.  Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer
but I've read mvc tutorials and still find it difficult to rewrite this code